# Can Apache authenticate automatically?

Tags: svn, authentication, apache-2.2

I'm sorry if the title isn't very precise, but that's really all there is to it.

I'm running Apache 2.2 on my computer to host a LAN subversion server. Since it's local-only, I don't need strict security, and there are no authentication directives set.

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /path/to/repos
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 192.168.1.0/8
</Location>
```

This works well to the extent of saving revisions of my files. However, there's no author specified in the revisions as there's no authentication.

My roommate will collaborate with me on certain projects, and while it's not strictly necessary, it'd be great if we were able to sort out who made what. Of course, I could set up a simple authentication realm with two users (and there's a possibility that it's the simplest way), however I'm wondering if it's possible to have Apache authenticate me and my roommate, at least as far as SVN is concerned, based on our static LAN IP addresses (or whatever else could be used transparently as an identification factor) rather than on WWW authentication.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Subversion: [use a DVCS instead](http://hginit.com/).

If you do use Subversion, note that it doesn't require Apache. It can also run on [local files, as a daemon, or tunneled over SSH](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.html). For example, by tunneling over SSH you can use public keys to authenticate automatically.